# E/Volley: [799] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 401 for

Tags: android, api, kotlin, android-volley

I am creating an android application using Co-WIN Public APIs.
I am using API for authentication using mobile and OTP.
send OTP work fine but confirm OTP, not working.
I am using volley to confirm OTP.

- https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/auth/public/confirmOTP/*

this is my code

```
         val url ="https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/auth/public/confirmOTP/"

           val params = HashMap<String, String>()
           params["otp"] = otp
           params["txnId"] = txnID
           params["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
           params["accept"] =  "application/json"

            val jsonObjectRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.POST, url, JSONObject(params as Map<*, *>),
        { response ->
        
            Log.d("verify otp", "opt success ${response.getString("token")}")
        },
        { it ->
         
         Log.d("faild request", "opt error ${it.localizedMessage}")

        }){

        override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
            val params: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
            params["otp"] = otp
            params["txnId"] = txnID
            return params
        }


        @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
        override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
            val params = HashMap<String, String>()
            params["otp"] = otp
            params["txnId"] = txnID
            params["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
            params["accept"] =  "application/json"
            return params
        }
```

I am getting this error.

```
          E/Volley: [799] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 401 
         for https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/auth/public/confirmOTP/
```